TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Row'
I'm trying to get some tuples for a selectfield from WTForms. but whenever the form tries to load I get the error TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Row'. im not sure where I went wrong with my code or if I'm just not understanding whats returned by my code.
Form
class NewSongForPlaylistForm(FlaskForm):
    """Form for adding a song to playlist."""

    song = SelectField('Song To Add', coerce=int)

flask route
@app.route("/playlists/<int:playlist_id>/add-song", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_song_to_playlist(playlist_id):
    """Add a playlist and redirect to list."""

    playlist = Playlist.query.get_or_404(playlist_id)
    form = NewSongForPlaylistForm()
    # Restrict form to songs not already on this playlist

    curr_on_playlist = [song.id for song in playlist.songs]
    form.song.choices =                 (db.session.query(Song.id,Song.title).filter(Song.id.notin_(curr_on_playlist)).all())

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_playlist_song = PlaylistSong(playlist_id=playlist_id, song_id=form.song.data)
        db.session.add(new_playlist_song)
        db.session.commit()
    

        return redirect(f"/playlists/{playlist_id}")

    return render_template("add_song_to_playlist.html",
                           playlist=playlist,
                           form=form)

template
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Add a song to {{ playlist.name }}</h1>

<h1>Add a form that when submitted adds a song to this playlist!</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {% for field in form
    if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}

    <p>

        {{ field.label }}
        {{ field }}

        {% for error in field.errors %}
        {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>

    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}


Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

db.session.query(...).all()

Is iterable of Rows but form.song.choices expect list of tuples. Just convert it
res = db.session.query(...).all()
form.song.choices = [(row.id, row.title) for row in res]


